# T-SQL query w/ grouping

Tags: t-sql, group-by, distinct

I have a query that looks like the following

```
SELECT t1.Name,
       t2.ID,
       t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Which gives me a massive list of values. But what I really want is only distinct values for t1.Name but with the related values for t2.ID and t2.name.

The only way I can think of doing it is using the Group By clause but then I have to use an aggregate function on t2.ID and t2.name. I've used MIN/MAX but then the values I'm getting for t2.ID and t2.name may not be from the same row.

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here. Thanks for the help guys

EDIT:
This is the actual query

```
SELECT (wi.wi_wpsnumbers), ws.*
FROM wi_weld_instance wi
INNER JOIN wlds_weld_section ws ON wi.weldinstanceid = ws.weldinstanceid
```

And this is the first few rows that is returned:

```
*999             100633    106*
*120,200,400     100656 44*
120,200,400   100656    46
120,200,400   100656    47
120,200,400   100656    48
120,200,400   100656    49
120,200,400   100656    50
120,200,400   100656    51
*123             100657 46*
123              100658 46
123              100659 46
123              100660 46
```

So what i'd really want is the first row, then the second then... where 123 appears in the first column etc. I have marked these rows with a star.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post a little bit more about the nature of your problem in order to get help that is actually useful to you. For instance, what is the nature of the FK relationship between table1 and table2? What is the context in which you're using this query? Etc...

Comment: There is a FK relationship on the ID's. We're trying to use the query as proof of a weld haven taken place. That's why I'm trying to remove duplicate values in the first column as we only need one example per weld type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use the DISTINCT keyword, which you seem to be hinting at already.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(t1.Name),
   t2.ID,
   t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: im guessing from the other posters that tSQL syntax here is a little different than MySQL.  Lose the parens

Comment: Using distinct looks for distinct rows, i.e distinct values in all three columns, I only want distinct values in the first column.

Comment: @gazamatazzer - If a particularly t1.Id corresponds to several rows in t2, this needs to be a somewhat arbitrary decision deciding which to include

Comment: this is true, I don't mind what values t2.ID and t2.Name have as-long as both these values are from the same row in table2.

Comment: I have just accepted this as you have tried to help me and I'm reposting a better question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name,
       t2.ID,
       t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Relevant information about DISTINCT from MSDN: 'Specifies that only unique rows can appear in the result set. Null values are considered equal for the purposes of the DISTINCT keyword.'

Comment: Using distinct looks for distinct rows, i.e distinct values in all three columns, I only want distinct values in the first column.

Comment: Can we get a sample table with sample return values then? I'm not fully understanding what you'd like returned.